# How to sync HTML5 Video Between Multiple Users

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, video.js

So I am using video.js as my video player on my website, but was curious if there was a way (either using video.js or another video player) to be able to sync a video between all devices on the website? It would be akin to Netflix Party / Youtube Party for videos. I am quite new to JS. Someone reccomended using a HTML5 library / methods, but I believe using websockets would be the smarter way to go.

For example, if Person A, Person B and Person C is viewing this video on my website, it would sync their video up so they are at the same time, and if either of them pauses then all three people see their video pause?

Comment: I would use WebSockets, but maybe there is a better solution. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket

Comment: @JakubMuda So I'm planning on using WebSockets, but here was the issue in my head. If a WebSocket has clients (watchers) connecting, then trying to take them to the point in the video the video is at won't be consistent right? If Person A is watching the video and is 40 seconds in, when Person B joins and I send the data of the video.currentTime() to the WebSocket to then be relayed to the HTML page, would it send the 40 seconds from Person A or the 0 seconds from Person B who is starting the video from the start as soon as they join?

Comment: I would do it the following way. First person to create a video party would become a "super user" who controls everything, has admin power etc, and anyone who joins should sync to the super user. You can do it in any way you want.

Comment: Yes that makes sense, I'm just super new to websocket so I'm unsure how to pull information from this 'super user', like how can I specify I want that specific person's video time.

Comment: @JakubMuda I made a new post here with my code, using some of your suggestions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67674870/websockets-sending-data-from-master-client